# error handling with http interceptor not working in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I am working on Angular 8

I am trying to centralise error handling through Interceptor

**My Interceptor code is running , but it is not returning any error**

```
import {
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpErrorResponse
   } from '@angular/common/http';
   import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
   import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { RestService } from './restservice';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable()
   export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private rest : RestService , private route : Router){}



    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      // console.log('jcsjdsjd');
      // console.error('xjxfjb');
      // console.log(request);
      // console.log(next);
      return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
        console.log(err);
          if (err.status === 401) {
              // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
              // this.authenticationService.logout();
              location.reload(true);
          }

          const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
          return throwError(error);
      }))
  }
}
```

**I have also defined interceptor in Providers of app.module.ts**

```
  providers: [RestService  , AuthGuard ,   commonRest    ,  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }],
```

response that I am getting on request with error 403 is  :

```
    {
  "messagecode": 403,
  "message": "not valid token!"
}
```

Comment: have you tried using tap() method and check if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) ?

Comment: @BrianDucca can you share a dummy code for using tap()

Comment: of course:  `return next.handle(request).pipe( tap(() => {},(err: any) => { if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) { if (err.status === 401) { //do your thing } } }));` and also add import `import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: @BrianDucca I tryed with you code  ->>>>



    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  console.log(request);
      console.log(next);
      return next.handle(request).pipe( tap(() => 
      {},(err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
         if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) { 
           console.log(err);
           if (err.status === 401) { console.log("It's 401");  } } }));
  }
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
But console inside next.handle(request) is not returning anything on error 403

Comment: Maybe the problem is how do you return your error in your api?, in my case, that code works perfect, i have an spring-boot API (Java) & Angular 8 frontend app. What is your api made of?

Comment: @BrianDucca Rubby On Rail , But how it will affect , if Interceptor Just works on response  by httpclient

Comment: the http status of the response is also a 403?, because in the post, it looks like you made your own response as JSON, but the status could be 200 + your Json response

Answer (score 1):

For use interceptor globally and the providers are in core module should add @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) in the top of interceptors like here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-interceptor-working-for-lazy-loaded-module?file=src/app/core/token-interceptor.service.ts

Comment: I'm not sure that by using `providedIn: 'root'` you can provide 'global' interceptors. Interceptors should be provided with the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` token.
Here's why: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/module.ts#L30-L44

Comment: when you work with lazy modules its the only way I make it works. you can see in the example that I use HTTP_INTERCEPTORS in core modules

Comment: I did notice that. But I can’t understand why you also added “providedIn”. I might be missing something

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your API returns JSON response in the following format,

```
{
   "status" : "403",
   "message" : "Session expired"
}
```

The following work for me, (I am having `tap` in the example below, in case if you want to extract something from a successful JSON response).

The errors can be handled in the `catchError` section. See, provided `error.status` examples for `403` & `401`. Feel free to customise that section.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(evt => {
        if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
          
        }
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        if (err.status === 403) {
          // Handle 403 specific errors
        } else if (err.status === 401) { 
          // Handle 401 specific errors
        }

        const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
        return throwError(error);
      }), map(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

        }
        return event;
      }), catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      // console.error(
      //   `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      //   `body was: ${error.error}`);

      // TODO :  do the logout here.
      // console.log(
      //   `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      //   `body was: ${error.error}`);
      // this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: '' }});
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(error);

  }
```

I hope this helps someone.

Thanks.